# I can not see the result. There is is a kind of adress on the result

Tags: python

```
class circle:
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, radius = 1) :
        self.radius = radius

    def perimeter (self):
        return 2* self.pi * self.radius
    def area (self):
        return self.pi * (self.radius**2 )

c1 = circle()
c2 = circle(5)
print(f"c1 Alan , cevre: {c1.area} , {c1.perimeter} \n c2 alan , cevre: {c2.perimeter} , {c2.area}")
```

below is the output,

```
c1 area ,  perimeter: <bound method circle.area of <__main__.circle object at 0x000002228E3A6E80>> , <bound method circle.perimeter of <__main__.circle object at 0x000002228E3A6E80>> 
c2 area , perimeter: <bound method circle.perimeter of <__main__.circle object at 0x000002228E3A6F28>> , <bound method circle.area of <__main__.circle object at 0x000002228E3A6F28>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the method by putting `()`

```
print(f"c1 Alan , cevre: {c1.area()} , {c1.perimeter()} \n c2 alan , cevre: {c2.perimeter()} , {c2.area()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `c1.area()` and `c1.perimeter()`.

Hope this helps :)